# Simulate slow connection with Sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I'm a frontend developer and when i code i use Sinatra as a static file server backend:

```
require 'sinatra'

configure do
  set :public_folder, File.dirname(__FILE__)
end

get '/' do
  send_file File.join(settings.public_folder, 'index.html')
end

get '/:name' do
  file = File.join(settings.public_folder, params[:name])
  if File.exist?(file)
    send_file file
  else
    halt 404
  end
end
```

I was happy with that, but this time i was given a task to create a JS intro that does some complex behavior only while the page is being loaded.

I'm unable to test such JS behavior because in my development sandbox Sinatra serves files immediately.

How do i make Sinatra serve files slowly, at given max rate, e. g. 10 Kbps? Alternative approach suggestons are also appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible if you split up a file into chunks and expose them gradually, here is an example:

```
require 'sinatra'
require "sinatra/streaming"

def file_chunks
  [].tap do |chunks|
    File.open("index.html", "rb") do |io|
      while not io.eof?
        chunks << io.read(10)
      end
    end
  end
end

get '/send_file_slowly' do
  stream do |out|
    file_chunks.each do |chunk|
      out.print chunk
      out.flush
      sleep 0.2
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Nice answer, +1 (wish it could be more).